# MVC PHP - html submit name not found in controller

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Alright so i have in my views a index that has a input type submit like so

```
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

When using the controller like so (to tests if it works)

```
public function indexAction()
{   
    $message = 'not submited';

    if(isset($_POST['submit']) === TRUE){
        $message = 'submited';
    }

    $this->view->setVars([
        'message' => $message
    ]);
}
```

and calling the variable message in my html with `echo $message`  i get not submited, what am i missing here ?

Comment: yeah i messed that up, edited now. Now its exacltey my code, which still wont work :/

Comment: Now the second sentence of the comment.

Comment: `(isset($_POST['submit']) === TRUE)` is redundant code.   `isset` already returns a boolean, so `(isset($_POST['submit']))` is sufficient without the qualifier.

Comment: @ChrisJ I have tried and still no result.. now it wont even output anything from the controller :/

Comment: @MewTwo - you haven't state which MVC framework you're using, but the following works as expected, so there's no reason why it wouldn't if adapted to your setVars:

```$message = 'not submitted';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $message = 'submitted';
}

?>

<form method="post" name="login_form">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php echo $message;```

Answer (score -2):

```
just erase " === TRUE"
```

just try this:

if (isset($_POST['submt'])).

And make sure that ur form method is set to "POST" and action to "#"